# How to toggle lines in a line chart using a legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is actually a continuation of the question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706745/how-to-assign-a-specific-id-to-each-line-in-a-multi-line-chart-with-multiple-y-a). I have made some changes to my fiddle and code since then but I am still facing the same problem. Link to my fiddle and code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kahmeng96/8v67whg9/174/).

I am using a for loop to plot the lines as I want the chart to be dynamic which means the number of lines is drawn according to the number of arrays in the data array. In this case, there are 2 arrays in my data array as shown below.

```
var data = [[{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 10, y: 10}, {x: 20, y: 20}, {x: 30, y: 30}, {x: 40, y: 40}], 
[{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 10, y: 200}, {x: 20, y: 300}, {x: 30, y: 400}, {x: 40, y: 500}]];
```

From my fiddle, the blue line will be toggled on and off when I click on both 'Y-Axis 1' and 'Y-Axis 2'. However, I want the red line to be toggled on and off when I click on Y-Axis 2. This is happening because I am assigning the same id to both lines in this piece of code.

```
    //************* Plotting of graph ***************
    var colors = ["blue", "red"];
    //plot of chart
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      var lineFunction = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {return x(d.x); })
      .y(function(d) {return yScale[i](d.y); })
      .curve(d3.curveLinear);

      //plot lines
      var paths = g.append("path")
      .attr("class", "path1")
      .attr("id", "blueLine")
      .attr("d", lineFunction(data[i]))
      .attr("stroke", colors[i])
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

      //plot a circle at each data point
      g.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data[i])
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x)} )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale[i](d.y); } )
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("class", "blackDot")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover )
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave )
    }
```

Is there a better way to plot the lines so that I can assign a specific id to each line being plotted and toggle the lines according to the legend? I have tried using forEach() but can't seem to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to create each legend element in your loop and add a event listener to each. See http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e99a762017060ce81c76

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have actually seen the code in the link and implemented it using d3.nest but to no avail as I get my data from an infotable on the Thingworx platform and not a .csv file. Do you mind looking at my fiddle and showing me how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you should **not** use a loop (`for`, `while`, `forEach` etc...) to append elements in a D3 code. That's not idiomatic, and you'll end up bending over backwards to fix things, like this very question will demonstrate.

The simplest fix without refactoring the code for a more idiomatic one, which will take a lot of work, is using the indices for setting the lines' IDs...

```
var paths = g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "path1")
    .attr("id", "blueLine" + i)
```

... and then, in the click listener, using this cumbersome and awkward `window` property, which is the elements' IDs:

```
.on("click", function(d, i) {
  var active = window["blueLine" + i].active ? false : true,
    newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
  d3.select("#blueLine" + i).style("opacity", newOpacity);
  window["blueLine" + i].active = active;
});
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var xValueArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40];
var arr = [
  [0, 10, 20, 30, 40],
  [0, 200, 300, 400, 500]
];
//data array is obtained after structuring arr array
var data = [
  [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 30,
    y: 30
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 40
  }],
  [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 10,
    y: 200
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 300
  }, {
    x: 30,
    y: 400
  }, {
    x: 40,
    y: 500
  }]
];

const margin = {
  left: 20,
  right: 20,
  top: 20,
  bottom: 80
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.selectAll("*").remove();

const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${80},${margin.top})`);

//************* Axes and Gridlines ***************

const xAxisG = g.append('g');
const yAxisG = g.append('g');

xAxisG.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'axis-label')
  .attr('x', width / 3)
  .attr('y', -10)
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .text(function(d) {
    return "X Axis";
  });

yAxisG.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'axis-label')
  .attr('id', 'primaryYLabel')
  .attr('x', -height / 2)
  .attr('y', -15)
  .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .style('fill', 'black')
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Y Axis 1";
  });

// interpolator for X axis -- inner plot region
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(xValueArray)])
  .range([0, width])
  .nice();

var yScale = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // interpolator for Y axis -- inner plot region
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(arr[i])])
    .range([0, height])
    .nice();
  yScale.push(y);
}

const xAxis = d3.axisTop()
  .scale(x)
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(2)
  .tickSize(-height)

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(yScale[0])
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(2)
  .tickSize(-width);

yAxisArray = new Array();
yAxisArray.push(yAxis);
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
  var yAxisSecondary = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(yScale[i])
    .ticks(5)
  yAxisArray.push(yAxisSecondary);
}

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(80,${height-80})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(80,20)")
  .call(yAxis);

//************* Mouseover ***************
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("background-color", "white")
  .style("border", "solid")
  .style("border-width", "1px")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .style("padding", "10px")
  .style("position", "absolute")

// A function that change this tooltip when the user hover a point.
// Its opacity is set to 1: we can now see it. Plus it set the text and position of tooltip depending on the datapoint (d)
var mouseover = function(d) {
  tooltip
    .html("x: " + d.x + "<br/>" + "y: " + d.y)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0] + 90) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
}

// A function that change this tooltip when the leaves a point: just need to set opacity to 0 again
var mouseleave = function(d) {
  tooltip
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 0)
}

//************* Plotting of graph ***************
var colors = ["blue", "red"];
//plot of chart
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var lineFunction = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale[i](d.y);
    })
    .curve(d3.curveLinear);

  //plot lines
  var paths = g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "path1")
    .attr("id", "blueLine" + i)
    .attr("d", lineFunction(data[i]))
    .attr("stroke", colors[i])
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  //plot a circle at each data point
  g.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data[i])
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.x)
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale[i](d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("class", "blackDot")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
}

var translation = 50;
var textTranslation = 0;
var yLabelArray = ["Y Axis 1", "Y Axis 2"];

//loop starts from 1 as primary y axis is already plotted
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + "," + 20 + ")")
    .call(yAxisArray[i]);

  yAxisG.append('text')
    .attr('x', -height / 2)
    .attr('y', -60)
    .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`)
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('fill', 'black')
    .text(yLabelArray[i]);

  translation -= 20;
  textTranslation += 20;
}

//************* Legend ***************
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend');

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('x', width - 5)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (i * 20) + 120;
  })
  .attr('width', 18)
  .attr('height', 4)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i]
  });

legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', width - 10)
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (i * 20) + 120;
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return yLabelArray[i]
  })
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    //Determine if current line is visible
    var active = window["blueLine" + i].active ? false : true,
      newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
    //Hide or show the elements
    d3.select("#blueLine" + i).style("opacity", newOpacity);
    //Update whether or not the elements are active
    window["blueLine" + i].active = active;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="xy_chart"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked and now I know how to use the indices for setting the lines' IDs. However, as it is not good practice to use a loop to append elements in d3, do you know how I can refactor my code by replacing the for loop?

Comment: Use a D3 enter selection instead.

Comment: Hi @Gerardo Furtado, do you mind looking at another question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741551/how-to-implement-zoom-and-brush-function-correctly-to-lines-and-points-in-chart)?